# why if condition is getting executed even condition fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, if-statement

I have put if condition to check i string is not empty then execute if block else nothing but it's getting executed even if string is empty, i ran debugger and it shows the value of string variable as "" but still it executes

```
string ComplainantContactNo = Convert.ToString(ViewState["CompContactNo"]);
if (ComplainantContactNo != null || ComplainantContactNo != "")
{
    ManageQueueBizz quebiz = new ManageQueueBizz();
    quebiz.Insert(ComplainantContactNo, "Your complaint has been registered successfully." + " \n Complaint Code: " + " " + OldComplaintCode + "." + " " + "To confirm your status send this complaint code." + "\n (Complaint Cell\n CPO,KP)", null, Convert.ToInt32(lblComplainantID.Text), null, null);  //Sms to complainant
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an OR so when you pass through `""` the first condition is `true` meaning that the OR condition is true no matter what.

us [IsNullOrEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: ok but if first condition fails so second would be checked , right ? in case of OR ?

Comment: @JohnNash That is correct. Short curcuiting means that in an OR if the first is true, none of the others are checked. But if it is false, then it keeps going till it gets a TRUE. The inverse is true for an AND condition.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is:

```
ComplainantContactNo != null || ComplainantContactNo != ""
```

An empty string is not null, so the first condition is true, so the code in the if statement runs. Remember, when you use "or" (`A || B`), the entire statement is considered true as long as either the left-hand side is true, the right-hand side is true, or both sides are true.

You probably meant to use 'and' instead:

```
ComplainantContactNo != null && ComplainantContactNo != ""
```

Now, the string must *both* be not null and not empty in order for the entire expression to be considered true.

Note that this is such a common operation that there's a built-in method to perform this check:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(ComplainantContactNo)
```

Comment: ok but if first condition fails so second would be checked , right ? in case of OR ?

Comment: @JohnNash -- yes, if the first condition in an OR statement fails, the second is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Your if conditions is translated to: Execute the following code if if `ComplainantContactNo` is not null or if is not empty string.

Or clause, needs at least one conditions to be true. In case of empty string, first condition is true and hence the code will be executed.

You may want to use something like this (.Net 4.0):

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace(ComplainantContactNo)){
// Execute code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Preferred way to check null or empty

```
If(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ComplainantContactNo))
{
    // Your code
}
```

From .net 4.0 Onward you can use IsNullOrWhiteSpace() Method which Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters

```
 If(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ComplainantContactNo))
    {
        // Your code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Let me briefly explain what happens;

Let's assume `ComplainantContactNo == null`, then;

`ComplainantContactNo != null || ComplainantContactNo != ""`

would become `false || true` which would result in `true`.

Same story when `ComplainantContactNo == ""`;

`ComplainantContactNo != null || ComplainantContactNo != ""`

would become `true || false` which would result in `true`.

Also, keep in mind that you want to test if the object is not null **and** is not an empty string. As the word says it, use the **AND**-operator.

For more information, take a look at [AND-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) and [OR-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx).